# drag and drop functionality for a watermark inside an imageview in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, watermark

I have an application where there is an Image view and a Edit text in android. Now whenever the user has entered the text in edittext, the text will appear on the top of imageview as a watermark text. I am able to achieve this thing, but i am not able to put a drag and drop functionality to that watermark text. I want the user to drag the watermark text and can drop anywhere inside the Image view.
Below is my code to redraw the Imageview with watermark Text:

Could anyone please help me in this, as I am stuck on this issue from past two days? 
Thanks in advance.
[image: create Watermark on image Method]

```
 fun redrawImage(): Bitmap? {
    val w = src.width
    val h = src.height
    val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.config)
    val canvas = Canvas(result)
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0F, 0F, null)
    val paint = Paint()
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK)
    paint.setAlpha(100)
    paint.setTextSize(26F)
    paint.setAntiAlias(true)
    paint.setUnderlineText(true)
    canvas.drawText(waterMarkEditText.text.toString(), 0F , 0F, paint)
    return result
}
```

I am calling the above method and passing the Image View bitmap to it to add the watermark text to the imageview.

Comment: Please copy and paste all the relevant code in your post and don't just include it as a screenshot.

Comment: hi @Nikos I have updated my question. Please check.